# Select Tag in HTML causing Issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a drop down field in survey page , it contains different value as shown in screenshot, the code is working fine Chrome but in IE i am getting an unwanted space problem in the drop down , i have tried different methods to fix this issue..

### HTML CODE

```
<select class="q_select">
<option value="" class="null"></option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="N"class="hide">N</option>  
    </select>
```

---

Kindly help me , Please find the attached screenshot for chrome and IE

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

-------------------------------**IE shown below**----------------
[image: IE]

I am setting a default value also in the select `<option value="" class="null"></option>`

Comment: Try setting some default value in the first option.

Comment: Please show the relevant html. Also, it would help if your two screenshots were for the same question number - how do we know the problem is with IE and not the particular question?

Comment: @nnnnnn : For all the question number same this is happening
unwanted space coming in IE not in chrome

Comment: I cant see your problem because if you på your html in jsfiddle you dont get any unwanted gap/space

Comment: Can you please tell me what are you trying to say i can't get your question